# Unable to download the pdf file from WebView. Always download .bin file. I checked in one plus mobile having android 10

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I try to download file inside a WebView. File is downloaded using browser but when I try to download through mobile WebView. It is download as .bin file. I checked this in android 10 device. It is working in below android 10. I was using Advance WebView library to open the WebView.  I am using below code for that. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) {


    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            Uri.parse(url));

    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
    request.setDescription("Downloading file...");

    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
            mimeType));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                    url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    dm.enqueue(request);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("dsfgh", "onDownloadRequested: "+url);

}
```

Comment: `request.setMimeType(mimeType);` You think that we now know which mimetype that would be?

Comment: `try to download file inside a WebView. ` ? There is nothing in the code you posted that has anything to do with a webview.

Comment: `File is downloaded using browser` No. You use DownloadManager for that.

Comment: `It is download as .bin file. ` What do you mean by that? Is the extension .bin instead of .pdf? Or what?

Comment: `I was using Advance WebView library to open the WebView. ` ?? I have no idea what you mean with 'opening a webview'.

Comment: @blackapps thanks ..it is solved now. Actually in the URL I was getting wrong mime type that's why it is downloaded as .bin file.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, Work For Me

```js
//    coding download
        webView.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, _ ->
            //checking Runtime permissions
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Do this, if permission granted
                    downloadDialog(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype)
                } else {
                    //Do this, if there is no permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                        100
                    )
                }
            } else {
                //Code for devices below API 23 or Marshmallow
                downloadDialog(url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype)
            }
        }


    }

    private fun downloadDialog(url: String?, userAgent: String?, contentDisposition: String?, mimetype: String?) {
        //getting file name from url
        val filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype)
        //Alertdialog
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        //title for AlertDialog
        builder.setTitle("Download")
        //message of AlertDialog
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to save $filename")
        //if YES button clicks
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
            //DownloadManager.Request created with url.
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            //cookie
            val cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)
            //Add cookie and User-Agent to request
            request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie)
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)
            //file mimetype
            request.setMimeType(mimetype)
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype))
            //file scanned by MediaScannar
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
            //Download is visible and its progress, after completion too.
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            //DownloadManager created
            val downloadmanager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            //Saving file in Download folder
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype))
            //download enqued
            downloadmanager.enqueue(request)
        }
        //If Cancel button clicks
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel")
        { dialog, _ ->
            //cancel the dialog if Cancel clicks
            dialog.cancel()
        }
        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
        //alertdialog shows
        dialog.show()
    }
```